# How to get Machine id using c++

Tags: c++, winapi

am facing two problems one big problem and one small problem :)
problem # 1 : am unable to read Machine ID from below path  ... i get my processor name like intel i7 @2.2ghz  like that , i do not know why , i should get machine id , long integer string but  i not get it , so please help

```
  reg_path="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography";    
  rvalue="MachineGuid";  // data value
```

my registery reading function

```
   string read_reg_sz(char rpath[],char rdata[])    // read registery Loaction
{
    REGSAM flag = KEY_WOW64_32KEY or KEY_WOW64_64KEY; 
    char buffer[MAX];   
    char Buffer[MAX];
    DWORD BufSize = _MAX_PATH;
    char dwMHz[MAX];
    DWORD dataType = REG_SZ;       
    HKEY hKey;
    long lError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,rpath,NULL, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | flag,&hKey);
    if(lError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
      {// if the key is not found, tell the user why:
           FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                         NULL,
                         lError,
                         0,
                         Buffer,
                         _MAX_PATH,
                         0);
            cout<<"\n reg erro : "<<Buffer;
           return "N/A";
       }
        // query the key:
        RegQueryValueEx(hKey,rdata,NULL,&dataType,(LPBYTE) &dwMHz,&BufSize);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);  // close open handle ....
    cout<<"\n reg data read: "<<dwMHz;
return dwMHz;
}
```

second problem :
currently i have function which can totally clean recycle bin :)

```
SHEmptyRecycleBin(NULL, NULL, SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION | SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI | SHERB_NOSOUND);
```

but i want to delete single file from recycle bin like passing filename

Comment: If you have two unrelated questions, please post them as separate questions.

Comment: second question is small so i cant post separate it says not meet our standards

Comment: If you actually describe WHAT goes wrong, it would help!

Comment: i mean i cant read the MachineGuid field value  from cryptography folder

Comment: path is   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography      ... there are sub folders in ctyptography folder , so that confusing little when i click on Cryptography folder i can see MachineGuid ... which i want to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really post it as two different questions, but I'll try to answer both.

## 1. Get MachineGuid

I think your issue is in this line:

```
    // query the key:
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey,rdata,NULL,&dataType,(LPBYTE) &dwMHz,&BufSize);
```

You should change it to:

```
    // query the key:
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey,rvalue,NULL,&dataType,(LPBYTE) &dwMHz,&BufSize);
```

By the way, dhMHz does not sound like right variable name - change it to reflect reality.

Also, you should have this:

```
 DWORD BufSize = sizeof(Buffer) - 1;
```

And, it would be nice to NOT have both `buffer` and `Buffer` variables.

## 2. Delete one file from recycle bin

According to Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on SHFileOperation, you should just use [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on filename like `C:\$Recycle.Bin\file.txt`:

- When used to delete a file, SHFileOperation permanently deletes the file unless you set the FOF_ALLOWUNDO flag in the fFlags member of the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure pointed to by lpFileOp. Setting that flag sends the file to the Recycle Bin. **If you want to simply delete a file and guarantee that it is not placed in the Recycle Bin, use DeleteFile**.

Comment: are you running on 64bit windows by chance? If yes, you may need to call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`

Comment: so how am going to use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection function ??? i have not used it before ..

Comment: You can either call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`, or you can add [KEY_WOW64_64KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag to your `RegOpenKeyEx` call

Comment: but i added the flag you can see my code   REGSAM flag = KEY_WOW64_32KEY or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;

Comment: Calling `DeleteFile()` only applies when deleting files that should not go into the Recycle Bin in the first place, not when deleting files that are already in the Recycle Bin.  The Recycle Bin is a virtual folder, it does not have an actual file system path that can be passed to `DeleteFile()`.

Comment: Nothing stops you from opening directory `c:\$Recycle.Bin` and looking what is inside (just don't use Windows Explorer for this). And guess what, `del c:\$Recycle.Bin\test.txt` - works just fine, file gets deleted for good.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a single file from the Recycle Bin, use `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(CSIDL_BITBUCKET)` or `SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_RecycleBinFolder)` to get the absolute PIDL of the Recycle Bin, then use `SHBindToObject()` to get the `IShellFolder` interface for it and call its `ParseDisplayName()` method to convert the desired filename into a relative PIDL, then use `SHBindToObject()` to get the `IContextMenu` interface for the file and call its `InvokeCommand()` method to execute the file's "delete" verb.